# How to patch the Tenacity decorator in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

My unit test is failing do to the Tenacity decorator, however, if comment it out, my unit test works. Any help would be appreciated. I've tried patching the _get_systems_chunk method because that's where the external call is made, but it doesn't work.

```
   @retry(
        stop=stop_after_attempt(5),
        wait=wait_exponential(multiplier=8, min=5, max=120),
    )
    def _get_systems_chunk(self, offset: int) -> dict:
        data = json.dumps(get_systems_payload(offset=str(offset), limit=str(self.config.page_size)))

        with requests.request(method="POST",
                              url=f"{self.config.base_url}/search",
                              headers=self.headers,
                              data=data) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            data = response.json()

        return data

    def get_systems(self) -> list[dict]:
        offset = 0
        system_details = []

        while True:
            data_chunk = self._get_systems_chunk(offset=offset)
            system_details.extend(data_chunk["mainObject"]["items"])
            offset += self.config.systems_page_size
            if offset > data_chunk["mainObject"]["totalHits"]:
                break

        return system_details

-----------

    @patch("src.gateways.ax.ax_service.AxService._get_systems_chunk")
    def test_get_systems_success_single(self, mock_get_systems_chunk, mock_systems_data, mock_ax_service):
        """Test successful retrieval of all systems in a single page."""

        mock_get_systems_chunk.return_value = mock_systems_data

        systems = mock_ax_service.get_systems()

        assert systems == mock_systems_data["mainObject"]["items"]

        mock_get_systems_chunk.assert_called_once_with(mock_ax_service._get_systems_chunk, offset=0)

        assert mock_systems_data == mock_get_systems_chunk.return_value


-----

        if actual != expected:
            cause = expected if isinstance(expected, Exception) else None
>           raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
E           AssertionError: expected call not found.
E           Expected: _get_systems_chunk(<MagicMock name='_get_systems_chunk' id='4335178880'>, offset=0)
E           Actual: _get_systems_chunk(offset=0)
```

Comment: I take that back, the code is now failing without using the retry decorator. It fails here, but passes everything else.

mock_get_systems_chunk.assert_called_once_with(mock_axon_service._get_systems_chunk, offset=0)

Comment: Figured out the issue. Changed the assert_called_once_with to the code below:

---

mock_get_systems_chunk.assert_called_once_with(offset=0)